# C# and Mysql about performance on Duplicate entry

Tags: c#, mysql

I am developing a program in C # and mysql, the C # application receives a lot of information, and does a lot of data insertion in to mysql, the problem is that sometimes it receives the same information many times, and it is not necessary to update it, so if for me i want ignore her. So from my point of view there are 3 options to control this event.

1.- Perform the insertion and leave it like this (not sure if this affects the performance)

2.- make a select and check if there is a key, if there exist then function exit, if it does not exist then insertion

3.- make an insert with the option ON DUPLICATE KEY or use IGNORE

I would like to know which is the best option considering that in fact are many inserts, and that I would not be interested to update.

**UPDATE**
C# Reciving data

```
    XmlDocument re= new XmlDocument();
    re.Load(url);
    m_schema = (XmlSchemaSet)util.LoadSchema(urlSchema);
    msg = re.OuterXml;
//Process Info
string sqlInsert =" Into Sport( Id_Event , Teams , eventTime ) values('12','xxxx','xxxx') ";
```

Comment: Post an example of your c# and mysql

Comment: the table is very simple have only 3 colums, and 1 primary key is like this Insert Into Sport(  `Id_Event` ,  `Teams` ,  `eventTime` )  values('12','xxxx','xxxx')

Comment: What type of c# program are you developing? Service, wpf, forms, web? Why not use something like cache storage in c# if you want to solve both your problem for duplicates and performance. Something like StackExchange.Redis? Because if you think of it, you don't want to access the persistence layer on every duplicate entry.

Comment: check the update please

Comment: yes,I was thinking about that too and I think that will be the best solution, and since sometimes i have to restart everything maybe i can combine the solution, for example use option 2, but save the result in a variable, and validate that variable later

Answer (score 0):

See the following c# Example for instance.

**c#**

```
using StackExchange.Redis;

// Will put this in contructor or config
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();

// XML 
XmlDocument re= new XmlDocument();
re.Load(url);
m_schema = (XmlSchemaSet)util.LoadSchema(urlSchema);
msg = re.OuterXml;

// Set value in cache with key
db.StringSet("ID", value /*, TimeSpan for expiry*/); // Replace ID with the duplicate entry

// Next time you want to process data... get the value / data 
string value = db.StringGet("ID"); // Replace ID with the duplicate entry

// check if exists in cache or is equal to the 'ID' then ignore otherwise process.
if (value == "" || value  != "SomeIDToCheckAgainst")
{

    //Process Info
    string sqlInsert =" Into Sport( Id_Event , Teams , eventTime ) values('12','xxxx','xxxx') ";

}
```

Hope this gives you some sort of an idea of what to do or what you can do. This is however if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: the ids no have order, then i think in create a list of string, and if no exist in list then i add the id in DB and List